# Abrir Formulario de otro proyecto C# (mvc)

Tags: c#, mvc, windows

tengo una duda si es posible hacerlo, estoy realizando un pequeño proycto en C# siguiendo el patron MVC, esta organizado de la siguiente forma:

- Proyecto 1(biblioteca de Clases): Acceso a datos
- Proyecto 2(biblioteca de Clases): Controlador (puente entre los form y el acceso a datos)
- Proyecto 3 (aplicacion windows form): Los formularios.

Mi duda es la siguiente desde el proyecto 2 podria ser mi main principal y llamar y acceder a todos los atributos de los formularios del proyecto tres.

Saludos

Comment: Si es posible solo basta con agregar la referencia de los otros proyectos e invocarlos.